# Uniqueness of mongodb index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-3.6

What is the difference of a unique vs  a non-unique index in Mongodb in terms of
1. `write performance` - i believe all indexes are defined as B-tree in mongodb.If so,is there any material difference between insert performance  in a collection having one vs the other
2. `read performance` - is there any fundamental difference in the way a lookup/read is done between the two types of index.

Comment: It makes no difference whether they are unique or non-unique indexes either. In order for MongoDB to find out documents, it needs to do an index traversal which operates in O(N)

Comment: Depends on how you define N there :)

Comment: Write performance will be affected since mongo needs to confirm there is no other record with the value. Read performance is exactly the same as a non-unique index. I don't have exact numbers on this but I doubt you'll need to worry about it unless you're doing massive amounts of writes per second.

Comment: That is exactly what I had confusion about - what is hte difference in complexity of search for a unique vs non-unique index during a write.In a B-tree ,it should be minimal ,if at all